# How to get all tables relation from sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have one database with collection of 30 tables.

I want to see that the relation between each table into that database.

i don't know how to get all database table relation.

Comment: Are you looking for a diagram which depicts the relation between tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get constrain information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables. The following script will give you a list of Primary and Foreign keys and tables.

```
WITH    PrimaryTable
          AS (
               SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME
                   ,i2.COLUMN_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                    ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
             )
    SELECT PK.TABLE_NAME AS PK_Table
           ,PT.COLUMN_NAME AS PK_Column
           ,FK.TABLE_NAME AS FK_Table
           ,CU.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_Column
           ,C.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS Constraint_Name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
            ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
            ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
            ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INNER JOIN PrimaryTable AS PT
            ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
```